# Solving a system of equations on Maple

Tags: maple

```
solve({4*a = 443*a1/(3.14)+a0, 7*a = 20*a1/(3.14)+a0, 105*a = 543*a1/(3.14)+a0}, {a, a1.a0});
```

Could someone tell me why MAPLE doens't compute this solution?
It doesn't give anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.  The second argument should be {a, a1, a0} not {a,a1.a0}

```
solve({4*a = 443*a1/(3.14)+a0, 7*a = 20*a1/(3.14)+a0, 105*a = 543*a1/(3.14)+a0}, {a, a1, a0});
```